# Model bicategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

From a conceptual point of view, the notion of a "model bicategory" is clear: a complete, cocomplete bicategory where there are two "very weak" factorization systems, where the commutativity of the squares you all know holds only up to specified invertible 2-cells, as in

[image]

I expect this notion to be either pervasive like the classical one, or empty.

What is the case? Is it possible to retrieve "familiar bimodel structures" in places which are bicategorical either because we are weakening a strict structure (categories + lax functors) or rather because their composition law is intrinsically defined up to a controllable isomorphism (spans, profunctors, presheaves with the convolution product induced by a promonoidal structure...)?

If this hasn't been done (like a rapid googling seems to suggest), where is the problem? Even forgetting any topological motivations, are you able to explain me *why* I shouldn't care about such a weakening?

Comment: Is there any example (which is not an honest model category)?

Comment: This is part of the question! :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I daresay 'no'.

Comment: To be honest, I think that the question "is there a model structure on the bicategory of $\cal V$-profunctors?" is valuable in its own right. Any such notion can't be a "honest model category", since the composition of profunctors is intrinsically defined up-to-something.

Comment: Aaron Mazel-Gee has been working on a theory of model $\infty$-categories (which suffices if you only care about invertible $2$-cells, I guess); you should ask him, or maybe I can summon him by writing this.

Comment: Or perhaps by writing @Aaron Mazel-Gee ...

Comment: @David: no, I think that only works if a user has already commented (or is the OP).

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not there are nontrivial examples, I would expect such a notion to be less *useful* than the classical one, because one of the points of the classical definition is to be able to use strict 1-categorical limit/colimit constructions to present homotopical information, whereas in a bicategory you're already being forced to use notions that are up-to-homotopy one dimension higher.  Moreover, since bicategories can be strictifed into 2-categories, I suspect that in most cases where there might be a model bicategory, there is also a model 2-category which falls under the classical theory, and that anyone interested in a strict model for the objects in question is using the latter instead.

Comment: Sometimes you want a model structure not to present a homotopical thing but because you want a well-behaved theory of localization. I think that's Aaron's motivation for thinking about model structures on $\infty$-categories.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan good point.  I say they would be _less_ useful, but they certainly wouldn't be useless.